# Interrupting a Jump Animation in windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, animation

So far, I have a jump animation. It uses an integer "jump" to loop through an array of images that create a jump animation, additionally, depending on what number "jump" is,the height "PositionY" will be increased or reduced and when jump hits 10, the animation ends..... this is jump animation code

```
    public Bitmap Jump_Frame2Draw()
    {
        Jump_Frames = new Bitmap[] { Jump_1, Jump_2, Jump_3, Jump_4, Jump_5, Jump_6, Jump_7,Jump_7,
        Jump_8, Jump_8 };
        if (jump < Jump_Frames.Length)
        {
            if (jump <= 3)
            {
                PositionY -= 30;
            }
            else if (jump == 8 || jump == 10)
            {
                PositionY += 0;
            }
            else
            {
                PositionY += 24;
            }
            jumpFrame = Jump_Frames[jump];
            jump++;
            if (jump == 10)
            {
                jumpTimer.Stop();
                isJumping = false;
                jump = 0;
                standTimer.Start();
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
        tracer = jumpFrame.GetPixel(1, 1);
        jumpFrame.MakeTransparent(tracer);
        isJumping = true;
        return jumpFrame;
    }
```

By using a timer and a paint event, I'm able to simply call this method every x seconds inorder to draw it when I press my designated jump key... Now my problem is lets say I'm in the middle of the jump animation, and I want to go back up .How do I do I go about that. Think of it as a double jump. Also, the jump and height(PositionY) are directly correlated. So if jump is 0,1,2 or 3, then height is 214 - (jump + 1) * 30). Else if jump is (5-9) height is 94 + (jump - 4) * 24). So the maximum height that any images will ever be drawn is 94.(its windows form so up is down and down is up... (0,0) is located at top left).

///////////

For a visual perspective, this is similar to my jump animation. This one is a little shorter in terms of time but it the best I could find.

Jump animation: https://media.giphy.com/media/wXervlFEqohO0/giphy.gif

now imagine this guy was ironman, he uses his jet boosters to jump up, but now while still in the air, he decided to just go straight up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'd save yourself alot of trouble if you move most of the animation-specific code to a dedicated `JumpAnimation` class. Pass all information required for the specific animation in the constructor:

```
class JumpAnimation
{
    public JumpAnimation(int howHigh)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Responding to a click on the space bar, you know you have to create a `JumpAnimation`. But while your timer is ticking, you don't want to deal with the specifics of a *jump* or *jetpack*  animation - you want an `IAnimation` interface that allows you to continue the animation whatever it was. And when you acitvate the jetpack, you just want to replace whatever animation is currently active with a `JetPackAnimation`:

In your form:

```
private IAnimation currentAnimation = null;
```

And the `IAnimation` interface:

```
public interface IAnimation
{
    // get the bitmap at the time relevant to the animation start
    Bitmap GetBitmapAt(int time); 
}
```

You can reuse alot of the code you shared in your question when you implement `IAnimation` in your `JumpAnimation`.

Now instead of returning just the `Bitmap`, you can create a class that holds more information about the "current step in the animation:

```
public class AnimationStep
{
    public Bitmap Bitmap { get; set; }
    // the y-offset
    public int OffsetY { get; set; }
    // indicates whether this was the last step of the animation
    public bool Completed { get; set; }
    // a jump animation can be interrupted by a jetpack animation, but a DieAnimation cant:
    public bool CanBeInterrupted { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I hope you get the idea. I'm not claiming this is the only or best way to tackle your problem, but sometimes another person's view on the matter helps thinking outside the box.

Comment: O btw, just wanna say thx for your view, stirred me towards the right direction and I learned what an interface is :). If you wanna see the working code, just tell me.

Comment: Good to hear, and nice of you to respond!